# How can I properly vertically align the centers of these pieces of text beside a switch toggle?

Tags: html, css

**Question:**

I'm a bit rusty at CSS, so this may be an easy question.

This is what the relevant section of my page looks like at the moment.

[image: toggle and text]

And I've pulled out the code as best as I can to replicate it in a JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/srap5maw/

I've fiddled around with it, and tried my Google-foo but can't find anything obvious.

**Code snippet:**

```
<div class="centering-table">
<div class="centering-row">
  <div class="centering-element">
    <b>Yes</b>
  </div>
  <div class="centering-element">
    <div class="switch-container">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="centering-element">
    <b>No</b>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your switch to a `block` (instead of `inline-block`) and then add `vertical-align:middle` to `.centering-element`.  I have also removed the line-height from `.centering-element`:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.centering-table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.centering-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.centering-element {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.centering-element b {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.switch-container {
    position: relative;
}

.switch input {
    display: none;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
    display: none;
}

.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border: 1px solid rgba(211,211,211, .8);
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #73c82b;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="centering-table">
  <div class="centering-row">
    <div class="centering-element">
      <b>Yes</b>
    </div>
    <div class="centering-element">
      <div class="switch-container">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centering-element">
      <b>No</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srap5maw/1)

Answer (score 2):

Define `.centering-row` as follows:

```
.centering-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And .switch should be a block element:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.centering-table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.centering-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.centering-element {
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.centering-element b {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.switch-container {
    position: relative;
}

.switch input {
    display: none;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
    display: none;
}

.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border: 1px solid rgba(211,211,211, .8);
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #73c82b;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="centering-table">
  <div class="centering-row">
    <div class="centering-element">
      <b>Yes</b>
    </div>
    <div class="centering-element">
      <div class="switch-container">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centering-element">
      <b>No</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex css to vertical center your stuffs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="centering-table">

    <div class="centering-element"><b>Yes</b></div>

    <div class="centering-element">
      <div class="switch-container">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="centering-element"><b>No</b></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.centering-table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: transparent;
}

.centering-row {
}

.centering-element {
    align-self: auto;
    background: transparent;
}

.centering-element b {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.switch input {
    display: none;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
    display: none;
}

.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border: 1px solid rgba(211,211,211, .8);
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #73c82b;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/srap5maw/2/. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **Just do :**
>
> 1) Insert `vertical-align: middle;` to `.centering-element`
>
> 2)Insert `vertical-align: middle;` to `.switch`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/srap5maw/5/)